# Using a DIV to mask another DIV

Tags: html, css, mask

This question is best explained with a screenshot:
http://i42.tinypic.com/2ccvx91.jpg

The wrapper div has a background image of a city.

```
#wrapper {
    background:url('city.jpg');
}
```

Inside that div is a bunch of other divs of class 'square':

```
.square {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#27272f;
    opacity:.8;
    margin:2px;
}
```

You can see through the squares to the city because of the opacity.  But you can also see through the spaces in between the squares, which I don't want it to do.  I want to only be able to see through the divs to the element behind it, with the spaces between them being solid black.  How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best bet is remove margin.. and give your div border of 2 px..

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the `border`  and using a wrapper div to hide the corners. You have to have a negative margin for the overlap to work though

[Here is the adapted jsfiddle from animuson](http://jsfiddle.net/8aRAm/1/):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="hidingborder">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidingborder">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidingborder">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidingborder">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidingborder">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

and here is the css

```
#wrapper {
    background:Green;
    font-size:0;
}
.square {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#27272f;
    opacity:.8;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
}
.hidingborder
{
   border:#27272f solid;
   display:inline-block; 
}
​
```

Comment: I thought this at first, but it wouldn't work with rounded corners. There would be a curved diamond at the center of every set of four squares. Also, the opacity would still affect the border unless he uses RGBA for the background.

Comment: if you are coding for new browsers..rounded corners work in pretty much all browsers now

Comment: @Joey: The border uses the opacity set for that element. [See this.](http://jsfiddle.net/xzAcm/3/)

Comment: @Joey Actually, I updated my answer based on animuson's jsfiddle..Using a wrapper div